# How do I call a controller method from a twig template and passing arguments to it?

Tags: 8, routes

I know I can pass variables to templates using render arrays.

```
$theme = 'block-AcademicDisplay';   

return array(
  '#theme' => $theme,
  '#content' => $content,
  '#url' => urlencode($url),
);
```

How can I pass variables and call controller methods from that template? On that template, when clicking on some buttons or links, I would like to call a controller method and pass it 2 parameters.

Comment: Hi @Matoeil 
Can you please share your solution if resolved?

Comment: i have used parameters upcasting in routes ( see below)

Answer (score 1):

**Passing arguments in route parameters**

I think the missing part is the route that you have defined for the controller. You have to use this to generate the url:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1]);
```

This example is for the node controller and passes the argument nid=1. The parameter names are defined in the route definition.

**Passing arguments in query parameters**

I've seen in one of your other posts that you want to use query parameters. This is an example for the user login:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('user.login', [], ['query' => ['destination' => 'http://example.com']]);
```

For this to work you don't need to define a query parameter in the route. Simply inject the request as function argument (the request is always available to a controller, it's not necessary to define it in the route) and get the query parameter:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  public function myController(Request $request) {

    $destination = $request->query->get('destination');

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used parameter upcasting in routes to convert dynamic values in url to object instances

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameter-upcasting-in-routes

in a bloc template listing all publications

```
 <a href="/publication/{{ row.halId_s }}">call to publication detail</a>
```

my_module.routing.yml , linking the route to the controller, with upcasting parameters

```
my_module.publication_detail:
#parameter upcasting
  path: '/publication/{halId_s}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::publicationDetail'
    _title: 'publication detail'
  options:
    parameters:
      halId_s:
        type: int
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

MyModuleController.php

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;

/**   
 *
 * for created routes publication/{}
 */
class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function publicationDetail($halId_s) {

    $module_global_config = \Drupal::configFactory()
      ->getEditable('amu_hal.settings');
    $amu_hal_url_ws = $module_global_config->get('amu_hal_url_ws');
    $docType_s = $module_global_config->get('docType_s');

    $url = $amu_hal_url_ws . 'search/?fl=title_s,en_title_s,docid,label_s,en_label_s,docType_s,authIdHal_s,halId_s,structId_i,uri_s,keyword_s,en_keyword_s,authLastNameFirstName_s,journalTitle_s,abstract_s,en_abstract_s,producedDate_tdate,producedDateY_i,language_s,fileMain_s&fq=halId_s:' . $halId_s;

    try {
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
      $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), TRUE);       
    } catch (ConnectException $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('amu_hal')->error('cette url n est pas bonne' . $url);
    }

    $theme = 'page-PublicationDetails';

    $module_path = file_create_url(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'));

    $build = [
      '#theme' => $theme,
      "#content" => $content,
      '#url' => $url,
      '#docTypes_array' => $docType_s,
      '#module_path' => $module_path,
    ];
    return $build;
  }

}
```

page-PublicationDetails.html.twig

```
{% for doc in content.response.docs %}    
      {{ doc.title_s|first }}
    // some more //    
 {% endfor %}
```